# If I have OpenRedis provisioned for our production server on Heroku can I share the same Redis service with Staging?

Tags: heroku, redis

OpenRedis doesn't have any free plans and so both production and staging need to have a paid plan.

Rather than do that I was considering connecting both applications to the same Redis plan. Is that sensible (I'm using it for Sidekiq) or am I going to get collisions? If it is sensible then how would I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you go that route, you should at least use a different DB for staging. You can change the DB by using the `SELECT` command, or just configuring it as the path in the `REDIS_URL` you use. If you are hitting the database a lot from staging, then you should check if it degrades your performance. Otherwise, if you use different databases you will be fine in terms of collisions.

Comment: good suggestion. It's probably worth just separating things entirely in all honesty. Thank you